# Find a cell in a row and copy values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I want to find a value in a row, that is, I want find "3" (which is in `D4`) in column `B`, when this value(3) has been found in `B"X"`, `D5` has to be the value of `B"X+1"`, `D6` has to be equal to `B"X+2"` and so on. Preferably, the solution has to be as formulas and not VBA.

Thanks by your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH($D$4,B:B,0)+ROW(1:1))
```

Put that in D5 and copy down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I forget to mentioned that for reducing memory, I want to avoid to use index  and match in all cells, I want something as D5 detect the cell where 3 has found in the column B, so D5 has to be the value of the next cell, something as D6 = value( D5 +1 cell)

Comment: INDEX/MATCH will be the least memory taxing formula possible.  All other options via formula will be volatile and have an impact on calculations.

Comment: @AlphaScorpion Index/Match in general is pretty low cost, and while there are alternatives, theres probably not a better way to do this than what Scott has presented here.  Is there a specific reason this solution won't work for you?

Comment: I understand...one extra question: in case that I use dates, is better index/match or workday ?

Comment: If you provide some test data and expected outcome you would probably get a more specific answer.  As is your question very vague as as such the only way we can answer is based on our perception of your needs. @AlphaScorpion